# How to change specific symbols in math mode

Tags: math-mode

I use `\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}` for math numbers, symbols, etc. but I want to change the `\sum` symbol to default computer modern one. When I use

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{CMlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\‎‏‎sum‎}{\mathop}{CMlargesymbols}{"50}‎‎‎
```

it results an error: `Command '\sum' already defined`. How can I change the `\sum` symbol?

Comment: Try "undefining" it first via `\let\sum\relax` *before* your `\DeclareMathSymbol` definition.

Comment: Related: [Importing a single symbol from a different font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/5764)

Comment: I get no error. Please, add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). The two commands about `\sum` should go *after* loading `mathdesign`.

Comment: @egreg the cause of this error is calling `amsmath` package. but i don't know why this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct loading order should be

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}

\DeclareSymbolFont{CMlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sum}{\mathop}{CMlargesymbols}{"50}

\usepackage{amsmath}                                       

\begin{document}

$\sum$

\end{document}
```

This is because `amsmath` patches some of the commands to become "dots-aware".

Answer (score 0):

How about if you try

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mysum}{\mathop}{CMlargesymbols}{"50}
```

and then at the end of the preamble

```
\renewcommand{\sum}{\mysum}
```

Comment: This should be by no means necessary.

Comment: my bad.  I should have tried a MWE to see if I got the same error.