# How to replace mathptmx \sum with CM \sum?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, mathptmx

I would like to replace the rather ugly `mathptmx` `\sum` operator with the equivalent Computer Modern one.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Importing a single symbol from a different font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/5764)

Comment: It's no different than done in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85991/how-to-change-specific-symbols-in-math-mode

Answer (score 1):

Here's a compilation of display-style `\sum` symbols provided by various font packages.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'd say that the summation symbol provided by the `mtpro2` package is closest to the one provided by the Computer Modern family, while still providing the genuine "Times Roman" look. Incidentally, the full [mtpro2](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) package isn't free of charge. However, its [`lite`](http://store.pctexstore.com/ma2lifoset.html) subset, which is all that's needed to produce the good-looking `\sum` symbol, may indeed be downloaded free of charge.

Here's the code that generated the preceding four lines (run consecutively for each choice of font family).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\usepackage{newtxmath}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm} \usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\ttfamily}p{4cm}>{$\displaystyle}l<{$}}    
Times Roman, mtpro2 & \sum
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey, do u think it is possible to use mtpro2's largesymbols with mathptmx? It kind of solves my problem.

Comment: @MiladO. - I would use the `mtpro2` package *instead of* `mathptmx`.