# How to change the style of summation symbol in the document class 'cas-dc' in Latex?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, els-cas

I have to use the `\documentclass[<options>]{cas-dc}` , and also I have used the following packages in my document in Latex.
The default style of the summation symbol in the document class `cas-dc` is:

[image]

How can I change it to the following style?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}
\usepackage{lipsum,capt-of,graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false, font={footnotesize}]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Fig. ,labelsep=period, justification=justified, singlelinecheck=off}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=newline,font=footnotesize, justification=justified, singlelinecheck=off}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\sffamily}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx, multirow}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{style=Plaintop, captionskip=0pt, capposition=top}


\begin{document}
\begin{equation*} \label{eq:Vpi(s)}
T = \sum_{t=0}^{M-1}f(x)
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The class `cas-dc` uses the Stix font (a Times New Roman variant), that contains the symbol in your screenshot as the sum symbol. You may be able to change that (see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85991/how-to-change-specific-symbols-in-math-mode and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font) but it is intended to be like this, if you use the class to submit to an Elsevier publication then it will be changed back to the default symbol by the publisher.

Comment: You shouldn't use `caption` and `subcaption` with this class, which has its own method for typesetting captions. Possibly `floatrow` is another no-go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add the following lines at the end of your preamble to redefine `\sum` to be the summation symbol used with computer modern.

```
\let\sum\relax
\DeclareSymbolFont{otherlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sum}{\mathop}{otherlargesymbols}{"50}
```

Here's the output with these added lines.

[image]

However, as said by @Marjin in the comments, I would not recommend to do that if it is to submit a manuscript, since the publisher probably needs that you stick with the font used in their document class.

Comment: thanks..........

Comment: Many compliments for your 10k...I am very happy to give +10 for this answer.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you very much!